# Is $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ a surd?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, arithmetic, extension-field

Is $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ a surd?

By definition an irrational root of a rational is called a surd.

Easy to observe that $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ is irrational. If not, $\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2$ being the reciprocal of $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$, is also rational, implying $(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)+(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2)=2\sqrt 3$ is also a rational, which is not true.

**Now the question is does there exist any $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)^{n}\in \mathbb Q$?**

It is clear to me $|\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2):\mathbb Q|=4$. But it is not really helping me. Looking for some help. Thanks.

Comment: Usually , with "surds" irrational numbers with a minimal polynomial with degree $2$ are meant , which is here not the case.

Comment: That is not the complete definition of a surd. A surd involved square roots, only, not "roots" more generally, and that is not the only part of the definition.

Comment: Specifically, surds are the smallest field of complex numbers closed under square roots.

Comment: So $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a surd?

Comment: @user371231 Yes, it is a surd. That definition with quadratic extensions is either wrong, or used only by some people.

Comment: The question is in bold.  Not what the word "surd" means.

Comment: You can apply the same technique that you used. If $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^n=(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{-n}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}\ni(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^n+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{n}$, for $n$ odd, expresses $\sqrt{3}$ as a rational. If $n$ is even, then $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^n$ expresses $\sqrt{6}$ as a rational.

Comment: And for those arguing about what is a surd, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Surd.html). It is not a serious term anyway. It is better to use more precise terminology.

Comment: Thanks @NDB, others. For some reason I have always thought that *surd* simply refers to *the symbol $\sqrt{\hphantom{W}}$.* In other words, I support the idea that *surd* is not *an official term* with an agreed upon definition, but some authors may used one. Which is fine within their context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is not a surd.

As you have correctly observed, ${\Big\lvert \mathbb{Q} {\left( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} \right)} : \mathbb{Q} \Big\rvert} = 4$. This allows us to know for a fact that if we can find a quartic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ that $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is a root of, then this is *the* minimal polynomial (up to multiplication by a constant, of course). Note that ${\left( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} \right)}^4 = {\left( 5 + 2 \sqrt{6} \right)}^2 = 49 + 20 \sqrt{6}$; this is also $10 {\left( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} \right)}^2 - 1 = 10 {\left( 5 + 2\sqrt{6} \right)} - 1 = 50 - 1 + 20 \sqrt{6}$. As such, $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is a root of $x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1$, which is the minimal polynomial. But it is then easy to see that this cannot be a factor of any $a x^n - b$, so no power of $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

In particular, if $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$ were a surd, then ${\left( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} \right)}^2 = 5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$ would be as well. But the minimal polynomial of the latter is $x^2 - 10 x + 1$, which is not a multiple of a cyclotomic polynomial and thus $5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$ cannot be a surd.

Comment: Check if you get $x^4-10x^2+1$

Comment: The minimal polynomial is $x^4-10x^2+1$, as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimal+polynomial+sqrt%283%29%2Bsqrt%282%29).  more importantly, you glide pretty quickly over the OP's question.  Maybe add some more detail?

Comment: I believe I have fixed it. Thanks for letting me know that I squared it wrong!

Comment: In fact my question was essentially that you mentioned in the last paragraph! Why not multiple of the cyclotomic poly over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: The only cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ that can divide a quadratic are $x - 1$, $x + 1$, $x^2 + x + 1$, $x^2 + 1$, and $x^2 - x + 1$. This is because (from Wikipedia): The degree of $\Phi _{n}$, or in other words the number of $n$th primitive roots of unity, is $\varphi{\left( n \right)}$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

For all $n > 6$, there are at least $3$ relatively prime numbers between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: I should have completed myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any $n$ such that $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^n \in \mathbb Q$?
No.  These four are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$:
$$
1,\quad\sqrt{2},\quad\sqrt{3},\quad \sqrt{6}
$$
If we write
$$
(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^n = a_n + b_n\sqrt{2}+c_n\sqrt{3}+d_n\sqrt{6}
$$
we may obtain recurrence
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= 2b_n+3c_n
\\
b_{n+1} &= a_n+3d_n
\\
c_{n+1} &= a_n+2d_n
\\
d_{n+1} &= b_n+c_n
\end{align}
We could solve this.  But it is simpler to note by induction that
$a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n \ge 0$ and $(c_{n+1}+d_{n+1}) \ge (c_n+d_n)$, so
every power $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^n$ has either $c_n \ne 0$ or $d_n \ne 0$,
and is therefore irrational.

Answer (score 3):

We have to show that, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+,$ then $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n\not\in\mathbb{Q}. $

Using NDB's hint in the comments, first we have that:

$$ \frac{1}{ \left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n } = \frac{1}{ \left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n } \cdot \frac{ \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n }{ \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n } = \frac{ \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n }{ \left(\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)\right)^n }$$

$$ = \frac{ \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n }{ \left(3-2\right)^n } = \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n. $$

Now suppose by way of contradiction, that $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n\in\mathbb{Q}.$

Since $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n\in\mathbb{Q}, \frac{1}{ \left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n } = \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n$ is also rational. Therefore their difference, $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n - \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n,$ is also rational.

You can check using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement) that:

$
\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n - \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n=
\begin{cases}
a\sqrt{2}\ \text{ for some } a\in\mathbb{N},&\text{if}\, n \text{ is odd}\\
b\sqrt{6}\ \text{ for some }  b\in\mathbb{N},&\text{if}\, n \text{ is even}.\\
\end{cases}
$

In either case, $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n - \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n$ is irrational. contradicting the fact that $\left(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\right)^n - \left(\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\right)^n$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$\displaystyle(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(\sqrt3)^{n-k}(\sqrt2)^k$ so

► if $n$ is odd then $\displaystyle(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\theta_k$ where $a_k$ is rational and $\theta_k$ is irrational.

►if $n$ is even then $\displaystyle(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^n=\sum_{k\space even} b_k+\sum_{k\space odd} a_k\theta_k$ where $a_k$, $b_k$  are rational,  $\theta_k$ is irrational and all the numbers are positive.

Thus never $\displaystyle(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^n$ is rational.

Comment: For the odd case, you would already have to have shown that rational linear combinations of square roots of non-square integers are irrational.

Comment: $A\sqrt3+B\sqrt2$ with $A,B$ rational it is quite known is not rational. In a HINT it is not  needed to say this.

Comment: Fair enough I guess

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: Cheers!